# How to make the margins and border in a mobile website invisible html/css

Tags: html, css, border

```
 *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}


#menubar * { padding: 0; margin: 2; }
    body { padding: 5px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width:95%; font-size:12px}
    #menubar ul{
 text-align:center;
}
    #menubar ul li { display:inline-block; padding: 2px;  position: relative; margin-left:-10px; margin-right:-20px; margin:invisible; }
    #menubar ul a { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 80px; height: 30px; text-align:center; background: #FFF; color:#000; border-style: solid; border-width:2px; border-color:#1570a6; text-decoration: none; }
#menubar li:after{
 border-left:50px solid black;
border-right:60px solid black;
content:"";
position:relative;
left:-12px;
top:-18px;  
z-index:-1;
display:block;
height:1px;
}
```

Ive got this code on the header and ive set the margin and border to 0 but im still getting a blank white space on the sides when i preview the webpage. Any suggestions?

This is the webpage that i have made and its for mobiles so if you want to get the proper user experience you could browse it with your mobile phone http://obdkey.comyr.com/Home.html

this is a temporary domain for the website

Comment: the body is still having 5px padding from all side.

Comment: Let me test that out and see if that is the problem im having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body still has 5px padding on it, set it to:

```
body {
    padding:0px;
}
```

You have a

```
<br />
```

that's causing the white space at the bottom of the page.

Also your width is set to 95%, which is causing the space on the right. 
Unsure as to whether that's intentional or not, but thought it worth a mention in case you were trying to get rid of that white space as well.

Comment: Yessssss. It was the width:95% which was causing the major problem and the padding was setting it off a bit as well. Forgot to remove them from the previous update i did. Cheers mate :)

Comment: Changed the break tag at the end as well. Good spottage :)

Comment: @AntonFernando Hah, fantastic! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
body { padding: 5px;
```

this may be your problem, try removing this attribute.